# RecyclerView разделитель

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview, cardview

**Дано:**

`RecyclerView` с элементами `CardView`. В каждом `CardView` есть 3 элемента - 1 `LinearLayout` и 2 `RelativeLayout`. В 2х `RelativeLayout` добавлены разделительная линия в виде `View`.

Минимальная версия `API`: 15

Максимальная: 23

**Проблема:**

При запуске приложения, в версии 5.0 и выше, всё отображается корректно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, при запуске приложения на 4.0 появляются лишние девайдеры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

Как убрать их в Android версии 4.0-4.1 и привести к такому же виду, как в 5.0?

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvChatRoom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"


        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/civChat"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                app:civ_shadow="true"
                app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"
                app:civ_shadow_radius="0" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twItemChatName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorChatName"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twLastMessageOrStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/twItemChatName"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/twItemChatName"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutEventInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">


                    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                        android:id="@+id/civItemType"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                        app:civ_shadow="true"
                        app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"
                        app:civ_shadow_radius="0" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twQuantityOfMembers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>



            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorToolbarLine"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twLastMessageData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                />


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorToolbarLine"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"


    >


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="ru.techmas.getmeet.activities.ChatsActivity"

        >
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/rwChatList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/footer_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему с линиями путём добавления в `CardView`:

```
    card:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Этл, также, возможно, результат прозрачности фона карточки